# How to change css_class for all <div> rows in Crispy form

Tags: django-forms, django-templates, django-crispy-forms

I am using Crispy forms to render my Django form. It works smoothly but I struggle with updating the css_class for my rows. Any suggestions how to solve this? The form is retrieved from the forms.models, so ideally I do not have to update my layout for every row individually.

The documentation https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/layouts.html#overriding-layout-objects-templates did not provide an answer to my question (or I did not understand it)

---

**Current output in html**

```
<div id="div_id_voornaam" class="form-group row"> </div>
```

**Ideally: change css class for every row:**

```
<div id="div_id_voornaam" class="row mb-3"> </div>
```

---

**Forms setting**

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.helper = FormHelper()
    self.helper.form_class = 'form-horizontal'
    self.helper.label_class = 'col-lg-2'
    self.helper.field_class = 'col-lg-8'
```

**Template setting**

```
<div class="card-body">
    <form method="post">
        {% load crispy_forms_tags %}

        {% csrf_token %}
        {% crispy form %}

        <button type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use wrapper_css atribute. Like this:

```
...self.helper.layout = Layout(Field('voornaam', wrapper_class="row mb-3"))
```

You can check crispy documentation here: https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/layouts.html

Comment: This saved my life! Or half of it - how can I set that for every input field, ideally globally in the project?